great expectation context issue when using multiple RunTimeBatchRequest using query
context =  gx.get_context()
           datasource_config = {
                    "name": "my_postgres_datasource",
                    "class_name": "Datasource",
                    "execution_engine": {
                        "class_name": "SqlAlchemyExecutionEngine",
                        # Modifying to check the connection string
                        "connection_string": f"postgresql+psycopg2://{self.db_params['user']}:{self.db_params['password']}@{self.db_params['host']}:{self.db_params['port']}/{self.db_params['database']}",
                    },
                    "data_connectors": {
                        "default_runtime_data_connector_name": {
                            "class_name": "RuntimeDataConnector",
                            "batch_identifiers": ["default_identifier_name"],
                        },
                        "default_inferred_data_connector_name": {
                            "class_name": "InferredAssetSqlDataConnector",
                            "include_schema_name": True,
                        },
                    },
                }
            context.add_datasource(**datasource_config)
            datasource = context.get_datasource("my_postgres_datasource")

***Above is my gx_context in which i have initalized my datasource

batch_request_1 = RuntimeBatchRequest(
                datasource_name="my_postgres_datasource",
                data_connector_name="default_runtime_data_connector_name",
                data_asset_name="asset_1",
                runtime_parameters={"query": query1},
                batch_identifiers={"default_identifier_name": "default_identifier_1"}
            )

            # Query 2 RuntimeBatchRequest
batch_request_2 = RuntimeBatchRequest(
                datasource_name="my_postgres_datasource",
                data_connector_name="default_runtime_data_connector_name",
                data_asset_name="asset_2",
                runtime_parameters={"query": query2},
                batch_identifiers={"default_identifier_name": "default_identifier_2"}
            )

***Above is my two runtimebatchrequest to handle two seperate queries

validator_query2 = self.gx_context.get_validator(batch_request = batch2, data_asset_name="asset_2")
validator_query1 = self.gx_context.get_validator(batch_request = batch1, data_asset_name="asset_1")

***Above are my validators but the issues here is that the last validator_query1 is overriding the validator_query2 and giving me two validator with same query, i am not understanding since a single context can handle multiple batches but here its failing to handle, why? can someone please help me with this
I wanted to get two validator for each query but instead i am getting two validator with same query but the last overrides the first validator

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
